# What is the scope of functions? Should i be using the variables that have already been instantiated?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm currently reading the first You Don't Know JS book, Up and Going. I am trying to build their first exercise based on purchasing phones and accessories but I'm having trouble and I don't understand why. I've simplified my code for this specific scenario to see if anyone might be able to assist here. None of my functions are working :( My output is as follows::

```
YDKJS2.js:38 Your total purchase before taxes is: 1049.9
YDKJS2.js:42 Your total purchase after taxes is: 1049.9
YDKJS2.js:46 Your remaining account balance is: function remBalance( bal , total ){
 bal = bal - total;

 return bal;
}
```

I've already tried using the same variables that were already instantiated and they are still not working.

```
const SPENDING_THRESHOLD = 200;
const TAX_RATE = 0.08;
const ACCESSORY_PRICE = 9.99;
const PHONE_PRICE = 199.99;

var totalPurchase = 0;
var numberPhones = 0;
var numberAccessories = 0;
var accountBalance;

function calculateTax( amt ){
 amt = amt + (amt * TAX_RATE);

 return amt;
}

function remBalance( bal , total ){
 bal = bal - total;

 return bal;
}

accountBalance = prompt( "How much money is in your bank account right now?" );

while( totalPurchase < accountBalance ){
 totalPurchase = totalPurchase + PHONE_PRICE;

 numberPhones++;

 if( PHONE_PRICE < SPENDING_THRESHOLD ){
 totalPurchase = totalPurchase + ACCESSORY_PRICE;

 numberAccessories++;
    }

}

console.log("Your total purchase before taxes is: " +totalPurchase);

calculateTax(totalPurchase);

console.log( "Your total purchase after taxes is: " + totalPurchase );

remBalance( accountBalance , totalPurchase);

console.log("Your remaining account balance is: " +remBalance);
```

Comment: `remBalance` is a *function* — you have to call it: `remBalance()`

Comment: Try using those functions in the same way you use `prompt`; use their *return value*.

Comment: Just an observation: you don't need to declare every variable and function in the top of your code because of something in javascript called hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting. Also you can declare your variables and constants inside the functions you are using them, so you can  I don't know about how this is covered in the book, though, but it's probably there.

Answer (score 0):

Scope it's like an area of visibility for variables/functions/etc. Usually you work in the global scope. If you write code inside function you start to use a function scope, restricted by its own variables, function, etc. But also, in normal case, you have access to the global scope and can use it.

In your example you should check where is a variable, where is a function. You use "remBalance" without braces, but before that you defined its like a function. So it needs to use like "remBalance(bal, total)".

Comment: I fixed everything! Thank you! By the way, what would you change in this logic if you wanted the program to stop running BEFORE it goes over the account balance? I was thinking of just changing the while loop to while( totalPurchase < (accountBalance - PHONE_PRICE) ) - would this be a proper way to do it? Or is there a way that would make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
const SPENDING_THRESHOLD = 200;
const TAX_RATE = 0.08;
const ACCESSORY_PRICE = 9.99;
const PHONE_PRICE = 199.99;
let totalPurchase = 0;
let numberPhones = 0;
let numberAccessories = 0;
let accountBalance = 973.17;
function calculateTax( amt ){
amt = amt + (amt * TAX_RATE);
return amt;
}
function remBalance( bal , total ){
bal = (bal - total);
return bal;
}

while( totalPurchase < accountBalance ){
totalPurchase = totalPurchase + PHONE_PRICE;
numberPhones++;
if( PHONE_PRICE < SPENDING_THRESHOLD ){
totalPurchase = totalPurchase + ACCESSORY_PRICE;
numberAccessories++;
}
}
console.log("Your total purchase before taxes is: " +totalPurchase);
totalPurchase = calculateTax(totalPurchase);
console.log( "Your total purchase after taxes is: " + totalPurchase );
accountBalance = remBalance( accountBalance , totalPurchase);
console.log("Your remaining account balance is: " + accountBalance);
```

Thank you for the help everyone!
:):):):):):)